# Process 'command 'C:/Users/xxxx/python.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, python, android, gradle, chaquopy

Good morning,

I'm developing a chatbot in android studio and I'm integrating a python script into my bot.
it was working fine using chaquopy, but then after I changed my application name, the whole project stopped working and it's giving me this error:

```
Build failed (with 1 error)

:clean (ok)

:app:clean (ok)

:app:preBuild (ok)

:app:preDebugBuild (ok)

:app:compileDebugAidl (ok)

:app:compileDebugRenderscript (ok)

:app:generateDebugBuildConfig (ok)

:app:extractPythonBuildPackages (ok)

:app:generateDebugPythonRequirements
Process 'command 'C:/Users/ashlibek/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Logcat is really long, and I couldn't figure out what is wrong from:

```
2021-03-20 09:02:44.558 7052-32520/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-03-20 09:02:51.529 14219-15679/? E/msgr.msys: E[N rtchannel]_rt_mqtt_publish_callback(356)=>Failed to publish the request over MQTT. token:624691b3-7763-4912-ac36-fcda5324bd31, category:mcd-sync-data-task-category, requestId:11634, error:Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
2021-03-20 09:02:51.538 14219-15679/? E/msgr.msys: E[N rtchannel]_rt_mqtt_publish_callback(356)=>Failed to publish the request over MQTT. token:d99da418-336b-452c-a712-6767184383f1, category:mcd-sync-data-task-category, requestId:14139, error:Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
2021-03-20 09:02:51.539 14219-15669/? E/msgr.msys: E[S sync]_createResponseError(166)=>Network Response 624691b3-7763-4912-ac36-fcda5324bd31 contains sync error Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008 - Underlying error (null): Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
2021-03-20 09:02:51.546 14219-15669/? E/msgr.msys: E[S sync]_createResponseError(166)=>Network Response d99da418-336b-452c-a712-6767184383f1 contains sync error Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008 - Underlying error (null): Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
2021-03-20 09:02:54.296 4289-4348/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 5646 [2021-03-20 09:02:54.295] FD count : 586
2021-03-20 09:03:00.005 5119-5119/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-20 09:03:00.040 5119-5119/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-20 09:03:19.903 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:19.905 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:19.927 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:19.930 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:19.943 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:19.946 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:19.949 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:19.955 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:19.958 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:19.972 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:19.969 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:19.974 19644-32531/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
2021-03-20 09:03:19.974 19644-32531/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
2021-03-20 09:03:19.975 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:19.979 3802-4025/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2021-03-20 09:03:19.988 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:19.990 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.004 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.022 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.026 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:20.036 4289-4560/? E/NetdEventListenerService: handleMessage: { when=-1ms what=10001 obj=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsResultParams@968a043 target=com.android.server.connectivity.NetdEventListenerService$DnsEventHandler }
2021-03-20 09:03:20.048 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:20.050 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.066 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.069 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:20.590 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:20.605 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:20.608 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.623 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.680 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.683 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:20.691 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:20.704 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.720 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:20.722 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:20.722 4289-7545/? E/WifiService: Permission violation - getConfiguredNetworks not allowed for uid=10190, packageName=com.tencent.mm, reason=java.lang.SecurityException: Location mode is disabled for the device
2021-03-20 09:03:20.736 4289-4504/? E/WifiService: 10190 has no permission about LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
2021-03-20 09:03:21.563 14219-15679/? E/msgr.msys: E[N rtchannel]_rt_mqtt_publish_callback(356)=>Failed to publish the request over MQTT. token:fcc5503f-754c-4804-b5bc-1c002add4e7a, category:mcd-sync-data-task-category, requestId:21044, error:Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
2021-03-20 09:03:21.570 14219-15669/? E/msgr.msys: E[S sync]_createResponseError(166)=>Network Response fcc5503f-754c-4804-b5bc-1c002add4e7a contains sync error Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008 - Underlying error (null): Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
2021-03-20 09:03:21.570 14219-15679/? E/msgr.msys: E[N rtchannel]_rt_mqtt_publish_callback(356)=>Failed to publish the request over MQTT. token:58cbb60d-c846-4c76-a6e0-9b9c6c1c0a93, category:mcd-sync-data-task-category, requestId:8130, error:Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
2021-03-20 09:03:21.578 14219-15669/? E/msgr.msys: E[S sync]_createResponseError(166)=>Network Response 58cbb60d-c846-4c76-a6e0-9b9c6c1c0a93 contains sync error Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008 - Underlying error (null): Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
2021-03-20 09:03:24.309 4289-4348/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 5647 [2021-03-20 09:03:24.309] FD count : 586
```

Any help or advice is really appreciated..Thank you all in advance!

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Does it work again if you change the name back? Are you able to determine *what was actually modified* when you "changed the project name" (i.e., what directories and files had their names changed, what file contents changed etc.)?

Comment: I'll try to change it back as you suggested and I'll see what happens. Thank you sir.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it back, but the problem remains the same.
I think I'll try to create another project and move all my packages to it. I can't see The logic in what I'm going to do, but I'll do it anyway. I'll update my answer if I got it working. Thanks alot.

Comment: If you had a build failure then the Logcat is irrelevant because your app was never run. But it doesn't look like you've included the whole build log. Click the "Build: failed" caption, then the log should appear in a pane to the right of the list of build steps. If you don't see that pane, it may have been resized down to nothing, so try dragging it back in from the right side.

Answer (score 2):

I got it solved, and this is what I did:

In build.gradle(Module), I had this:

```
python { 
        buildPython "C:/Users/xxx/Python38/python.exe"
        
        pip {
            install "chatterbot==1.0.4"
            install "PyYAML==3.13"
            install "chatterbot_corpus==1.2.0"
            install "click-7.1.2"
            install "joblib-1.0.1"
            install "mathparse-0.1.2"
            install "nltk-3.5"
            install "packaging-20.9"
            install "pint-0.16.1"
            install "pymongo-3.11.3"
            install "pyparsing-2.4.7"
            install "python-dateutil-2.7.5"
            install "regex-2020.11.13"
            install "six-1.15.0"
            install "sqlalchemy-1.2.19"
            install "tqdm-4.59.0"
        }
    }
```

Somehow, after I updated python from 3.7.8 to 3.8.6, the PiP block stopped running smoothley, for now I uncommented all these packages except for Chatterbot and my app is working fine again (I haven't gone through all its features but at least it's building fine for now).

I don't know why this happened and I'm gonna investigate it more just to understand it, but I hope my solution will save another one's time.

Thanks.

Comment: See my comment above for how to view the build log with the full error details. In this case, the cause is probably that you're using the wrong syntax for version numbers: they should be separated by `==`, not `-`. See the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) for details.

Comment: @mhsmith Actually it was working fine before I upgraded python and chaquopy, but I'll keep your advices in my mind when I further investigate the cause for this problem..Thank you sir, and by the way you did an amazing job with chaquopy!